# Python Reporting Frameworks

Tags: python, reporting, toolkit, dynamic-reports

Does anyone have/know of a Python Reporting Framework along the lines of what something like [DynamicReports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html#overview) does?

Comment: Note to self : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pigpy/0.6

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would just use django (perhaps with [django-reporting](http://code.google.com/p/django-reporting/)) to do the job. If django isn't an option, perhaps SQLAlchemy would be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Just leaving this link here

https://github.com/ra-systems/django-slick-reporting

It's a reporting engine where you can create grouped by computed reports, time series and crosstab using handful of easy lines of code. It also comes with Charting out of the box. *disclaimer: i'm the author*

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it, but [ReportLab Toolkit](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/) is probably your best bet. Perhaps with [podunk](http://code.google.com/p/podunk/) added on to make it a bit easier.

Comment: This does some neat things as far as layout (very cool) but does almost nothing to slice/manage the data presented.